# Block pointer events on child items when hidden by overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have clickable items hidden by `overflow: hidden` and I don't want the user to click on the hidden items (thinking they're clicking the ellipsis to expand) because it will make changes the user probably doesn't want. Is there a way to block pointer-events on those items when they're hidden?

In this snippet [fiddle], hover your mouse to the right of the ellipsis to see that the hover event is still sent through to hidden items. [https://jsfiddle.net/thebradness/25xy376d/23/]

I've tried different combinations of the pointer-events property between the parent and children but they all apply the same way to children hidden and unhidden.

```css
.item {
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 26px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">item1</div>
  <div class="item">item2</div>
  <div class="item">item3</div>
  <div class="item">item4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is kind of strange. I think we're missing important info. If we look at what's there, without any more info, the thought is, just delete the stuff you're not using. But I imagine you're going to use it and hide it. Then, how are you going to hide it? JS? In which case there are several things you can do. But JS is not part of the question.

Comment: The number of children can vary (they're like applied filters in a search). The wrapper takes up most of the width of the page but resizing the page will change the width of the wrapper and hide more child items.

Comment: Each item/applied search filter has a little X on it to clear it. So I don't want users to clear a search term when they thought they were clicking on the "..." to expand it.

Comment: I'm currently facing this issue, still don't know how to fix this